# How to resolve variable increment issue in a recursive function

Tags: scala

Trying to create a pascals triangle using recursive function. Returning value is always zero.

I'm new to Scala programming and not sure if the declaring the `value` variable in the code is the right way. Appreciate any help with the right approach. Thanks

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Pascal's Triangle")
    for (row <- 0 to 10) {
      for (col <- 0 to row)
        print(pascal(col, row) + " ")
      println()

    }
  }

  var value: Int = 0
  def pascal(c: Int, r: Int): Int = {
    if (c ==0) 1
    else if (c == r ) 1
    else
      for (col <- c-1 to c) {
        value +=   pascal(col, r - 1)
      }
      value
    }
  }
```

Actual Result

```
Pascal's Triangle
0 
0 0 
0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Expected Result

```
Pascal's Triangle
1 
1 1 
1 2 1 
1 3 3 1 
1 4 6 4 1 
1 5 10 10 5 1 
1 6 15 20 15 6 1 
1 7 21 35 35 21 7 1 
1 8 28 56 70 56 28 8 1 
1 9 36 84 126 126 84 36 9 1 
1 10 45 120 210 252 210 120 45 10 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using var. In this case, you don't need it. Avoid var, use val. Such is good functional programming practice.

```
object Pascal {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Pascal's Triangle")
    for (row <- 0 to 10) {
      for (col <- 0 to row)
        print(pascal(col, row) + " ")
      println()

    }
  }

  def pascal(c: Int, r: Int): Int = {
    if (c ==0) 1
    else if (c == r ) 1
    else {
      val intermediate = for (col <- c - 1 to c) yield pascal(col, r - 1)
      intermediate.sum
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I was looking for. I have question, in procedural programming incrementing a variable is a frequent operation(for example counting), how to handle such kind of scenarios using a val variable?

Comment: Usually, in imperative programming, you increment variable as part of a loop. In functional programming, instead of incrementing a variable in a loop, you increment a val and pass it as a parameter to the next call of a recursive function. Another case is if you just want the keep track of the index of an item in a sequence. If you just want the index of a value in a sequence, use the zipWith function.

Comment: @Midhun If you don't understand the first part of my previous answer, try doing some example problems relating to recursion. It will demonstrate what I mean by incrementing a value and passing it as a parameter to a recursive function.

Answer (score 2):

Scala style tries to avoid mutable data (i.e. `var`).

```scala
def pascalTriangle(height :Int) :Unit =
  Iterator.iterate(Vector(1))(v => (0+:v:+0).sliding(2).map(_.sum).toVector)
          .take(height)          //take only as many as needed
          .map(_.mkString(" "))  //turn Vector into space separated String
          .foreach(println)      //force the calculations
```

Here we create an infinite collection of `Vector`s, each one longer than the previous. Each `Vector` is processed to create the required sums, but none of that happens until the `foreach()` because an `Iterator` is lazy.